# sequalize Search in Association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
using sequelize 3.30.1
```

I have two models Category and Product related through association .

```
var Category = sequelize.define('Category',
  { name: DataTypes.STRING });

};

var Product = sequelize.define("Product", {

price:{type:DataTypes.INTEGER,UNSIGNED:true},
 {
   classMethods: {
   associate: function() {

    Product.belongsTo(Category, {
      foreignKey: {
         name: 'category',
         allowNull: false
      }
    });

 });
```

how can i search for product with `Category.name` like `%CatName%` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but just had to re-format your code:

```
var Category = sequelize.define('Category',
  {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  });

var Product = sequelize.define("Product",
  {
    price: {
     type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     UNSIGNED:true
    },
    classMethods: {
      associate: function() {
        Product.belongsTo(Category, {foreignKey: {name: 'category', allowNull: false}});
      }
    }
  });
```

Now that you have the two models and defined an association, you can use the findAll() method to query.

```
var catName = 'book';

Product.findAll({
  include : [
    {
      model: Category,
      where: {
        name: {
          $like: '%' + catName + '%'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
.then(function(
   console.log(result);
});
```

See if this works.